# How to write a text from excel file into an image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pycharm, anaconda

```
import pandas as pd
 
# read by default 1st sheet of an excel file
dataframe1 = pd.read_excel(r'E:\Images\New Folder\afec9b91-5c2f-4cab-aca8-abd7bde854e0\P_SA_C0002_DcW_R1_01_FMV_000000000000.xlsx')
print(dataframe1)
```

Output

```
  Sensor Longitude   Sensor Latitude             Survey ID
      72.69362         32.090865                 P_SA_C0002_DcW_R1_01
```

Now I want that output to written on specific image.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import glob
import os

images=glob.glob("E:\Images/*.jpg")

for img in images:
    images=Image.open(img)
    draw=ImageDraw.Draw(images)
    font=ImageFont.load_default()
    import pandas as pd
 
# read by default 1st sheet of an excel file
dataframe1 = pd.read_excel(r'E:\Images\New Folder\afec9b91-5c2f-4cab-aca8-abd7bde854e0\P_SA_C0002_DcW_R1_01_FMV_000000000000.xlsx')
#print(dataframe1)
   # write ="dataframe1"
   
    text="print"

   
    draw.text((0,240),text,(250,250,250),font=font)
    images.save(img)
```

I am trying to write the output on image by using above code by its not working.Please help.

Comment: Your indentation is a bit confused.  Is the `dataframe1` line supposed to be indented to be part of the `for` loop?

Comment: Your basic code works fine for me.  Remember that the default font is very small (like about 8 pixels) and you are writing in nearly white.